# Computing $h(h(x))$ where $h (x) = \lfloor 5x - 2 \rfloor$

Tags: functions, solution-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In Velleman's "Calculus: a Rigorous Course," Example 9 from Section 1.3 tasks us with computing $ h(h(x)) $, where $ h(x) = \lfloor 5x - 2 \rfloor $.

My initial solution:

\begin{align*}
h(\lfloor 5x - 2 \rfloor) &= \lfloor 5(\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 2) - 2 \rfloor \\
&= \lfloor 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 10 \rfloor - 2 \\
&= \lfloor 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor \rfloor - 12
\end{align*}

However, the provided solution from the book is:

$ 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 12 $

How can I get the correct solution ?

Comment: The output of the ceiling function is an integer; an integer multiplied by $5$ is again an integer.

Comment: Thank you, Mauro !

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That's the *floor* function, not the ceiling function. Not that it matters here.

Comment: If $M$ is an integer then $[M]$.  And as $[5x]$ is an integer so is $5[5x]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it!

$\begin{align*}
h(\lfloor 5x - 2 \rfloor) &= \lfloor 5(\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 2) - 2 \rfloor \\
&= \lfloor 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 10 \rfloor - 2 \\
&= \lfloor 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor \rfloor - 12
\end{align*}$

Then, since $\lfloor 5x \rfloor $ is always an integer we get that $5 \times \lfloor 5x \rfloor $ is also an integer so the outer floor is not needed indeed

So we get $h(h(x))= 5\lfloor 5x \rfloor - 12$

So we can say $\lfloor a\lfloor b \rfloor \rfloor = a \times \lfloor b \rfloor $ , when $a$ is an integer .